# Outlook 2016 HTML Signature

Tags: email, ms-office, html, signature

I'm trying to add an HTML E-Mail signature to Outlook 2016 for macOS. The method that got me closest to my goal is documented here:

http://mydesignpad.com/how-to-create-an-attractive-html-email-signature-for-microsoft-outlook-2016-for-mac/

This approach *works perfect* when I add the signature in **Outlook Web Access (owa)**. As to say the recipient sees the signature formatted as intended and the **image is downloaded from a external server**. Also the message shows **no attachment clip** in the inbox of whatever E-Mail client.

But when I add the signature to **Outlook for Mac (Version 15.36)** the embedded image is being downloaded before sending a E-Mail and **gets included as an attachment**. So the message **does show an attachment clip** in the inbox of whatever E-Mail client.

Does anybody experience same issues? Has someone found a solution/work around?

Comment: I've stumbled across an app called **ThunderWiz** on the Mac App Sotre for managing more than 1 signature. Haven't tried HTML formatted signatures yet but I can't see why it wouldn't handle it: https://apple.co/2KHStCe

Answer (score 1):

Outlook works best with a restricted version of HTML for the signature, so if you can't use the webmail signature generator and copy / paste that into your Mac Outlook - look for a third party tool to assist.

One that works well is this utility from the App Store. It fixes the problem with Outlook breaking HTML signature. Costs about USD 3 though but for me it's worth it.

[HTML Email Signature for Outlook - Daniel Caspi](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/html-email-signature-for-outlook/id1101267774?mt=12&at=1010lGjQ)